# read into variable with while-loop terminates with 'Range_error' on C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

attempting to code a drill from C++ study book, "Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered."
i coded the following:

```
#include "C:\Users\Erez\Documents\Dev C++ Projects\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main(){
   vector<int> v;
   int value {0};
   int i {1};
   while (cin >> value)
   {
      v.push_back(value);
      if (i % 2 == 0) { //using the % modulo to cout couples.
         cout << v[i] << '\t' << v[i-1] << "\n"; // cout i + (i-1)
      }
      ++i;
   }
}
```

feeding two values separated by either space or line, i get this error:

4
5
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Range_error'
  what():  Range error: 2

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: It seems to me that `v[i]` is off the end of your vector. You've pushed 2 ints into v, so the valid indexes would be 0 and 1, but `i` will be 2, so you're accessing `v[2]` and `v[1]`. But I would think it wouldn't print anything before throwing.

Comment: Gracias muchacos! I replaced index size with vector size and it works as expected :) appreciate you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indices into vectors, arrays, etc. *start at index 0*

You are initializing your index to 1 and incrementing from there.

Thus, v[i] is referring to the value *after* the last one you pushed.  This is an attempt to access something out of bounds and it is causing your program to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement of:

```
if (i % 2 == 0){
//
}
```

becomes `true` on second iteration inside your `while` loop and the statement of:

```
cout << v[i] << '\t' << v[i-1] << "\n"; // cout i + (i-1)
```

gets executed. The culprit here is `v[i]` which is actually `v[2]`. By now your vector only has two elements: `v[0]` and `v[1]`, meaning that with the `v[2]` you are trying to read out of bounds. Rethink the logic inside your `while` statement and initialize the `i` counter to *0* rather than *1* to begin with. If you are trying to print out even vector elements then it should be:

```
if (v[i] % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: I think if you initialize `i` to to zero then the `if (i % 2 == 0)` will become true on the first iteration of the loop, and will cause an out of bounds error on the `v[i-1]` in the cout.